# Using Boost Python to wrap C++ arrays into numpy arrays

Tags: c++, python, boost, numpy, boost-python

Suppose I have a C++ struct

```
struct A {
  int* a; 
}
```

Where int*a points to an array. How do I expose this to Python, which has a as a numpy array, with `dtype = 'int'`?

Comment: Have you seen this example http://www.shocksolution.com/python-basics-tutorials-and-examples/boostpython-numpy-example/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear from your question what do boost::python has to do with this. But if you want to just expose the array to python as a numpy array, you can use [PyArray_SimpleNewFromData](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_SimpleNewFromData).

If you want to expose the whole A struct with boost::python, and `a' as a member of it, use the boost::python syntax for properties, and the previous function for returning an array view of your struct. Note that you will need to know the size of the array for exposing it to Python.